# How to align two column together in a <a tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I trying to align or to put on the same line this HTML

Actual output looks like this

```
 Cart:

 Payment >>

 Add another item >>

 Product    Price   Quantity

 Toaster    19.99    1         Update Cart                            
                                             Remove from Cart <== I want this column align with
                                                                  the update cart or on the same
                                                                  line

 Total                     19.99
```

I will like to have the Update Cart and Remove on different line but align
or have them on the same line

Here is the Index.cshtml

```
        @{int ix = 0;}

        @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
        {
           <tr id="row-@item.ProductId">
              <td>
                   @Html.ActionLink(item.Produit.Description, "Details", "Product", new { id = 
                        item.ProduitId }, null)
              </td>
              <td>
                @item.Product.Price
              </td>
              <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartItems[ix].Quantity, 
                    new  {style = "width:30px; text-align:right;",
                    onkeyup = "clearUpdateMessage();",
                    onchange = "clearUpdateMessage();"
                    }) 
              </td>
              <td>
                <a href="#" class="RefreshQuantity" data-id="@item.PanierId" 
                    id="CartItems_@(ix)__Quantity"> Update Cart >> <a />
              </td>

              <td>
                 <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.PanierId"> Remove from Cart >> 
                 </a>
              </td>
           </tr>
           ix++;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the css width property on the individual td's.

```
 <td style="width: 100px"> //or use % if your planning on multiple media</td>
 <td style="width: 100px:> </td>
```

set the size of the td's accordingly.

You may want to look into [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), this library makes CSS very easy to manipulate with classes

UPDATE:

Using % instead of pixels is difficult to show in a small sampling. I do not know what you want your screen to look like when you switch media. It can be something as simple as you want your screen to shrink when swapping media.

```
 <td style="width: 15%"> </td>
```

It could be that you want to change the layout if you swap to something as small as a phone in which case you will want to create css classes for specific media.

With the world moving toward Write Once, Run Anywhere (WORA) development (twitter bootstrap, xamarin, PhoneGap, etc...) You will have to decide for yourself what is best for your case.

UPDATE:

[Here is a fiddle of what I am suggesting](http://jsfiddle.net/rr9fx/)

Comment: can you provide me an example with %   what do you means by media ?

Comment: I put my output layout (see in my description of the problem)  I tried the width:100 px in each one but it comes out exactly like I said in the description

Comment: Try decreasing the px size and see if you get a different result.

Comment: I am trying CTRL-F5 to refresh the CSS (using Chrome) because sometimes the Css is not refreshing.  so far same problem with 50px

Comment: It is working now.  I didn't realize the style="width:100px" should be inside the <td style..... >   I was putting it in the <a this is why it was not working.   Thanks a lot for your solution !!